# Why does this "nested join" works with PDO but not with MySql cli?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pdo

I don't understand why this query works and what it actually means. It should be noted that this query works when using PDO but doesn't through Mysql cli or even phpmyadmin.

```
   SELECT table1.something, table2.something 
   FROM someTable
   LEFT JOIN table 1
     INNER JOIN table2
       ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
     ON table1.account_id = someTable.account_id
```

No errors are thrown and, even weirder, I actually have results that are coherent with what the query is supposed to do.

Comment: SQL queries don't begin with `LEFT JOIN`, ever.  Please show us the actual complete query you are running.

Comment: JOIN ... ON ... JOIN ... ON

Comment: If this is the entire query, it will not work in any environment that I'm aware of.  Because you claim it works somewhere, I interpreted your question as being about a subset of the `FROM` clause.  You should clarify.

Comment: Changed query according to your demands. I've spared you the other joins and selects.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid SQL syntax, assuming you have just taken a snippet from the `FROM` clause.  It is interpreted as:

```
SELECT table1.something, table2.something
FROM someTable
LEFT JOIN
(table1 INNER JOIN
 table2 bbm
 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
)
ON table1.account_id = table2.account_id
```

That said, this is *really* arcane, because the alias renames `table2` to `bbm`, which is not used.  The `ON` conditions are only referring to earlier tables.  The result is some strange form of `CROSS JOIN`.

That you can nest `JOIN`s this way should -- in my opinion -- be merely viewed as an amusement.  Don't nest `JOIN`s.  Each `JOIN` should be followed by its very own `ON` clause, before the next table/subquery reference.  Nesting joins makes the code is harder to understand.  It can introduce errors (which I think happened in this case).  There can also be subtle edge cases where it is a little challenging to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Is this really valid in MySQL though?  If there is no select list, how can any API work?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, a long time ago the SQL standard actually allowed queries similar to the one above, i.e. `tablename1 join tablename2 on ...` - without select list. (Was later removed.)

Comment: There is a from in the original query though. I've just isolated the part that made the query bug. It is now edited. Gordon, could you edit yours according to mine ? I've added the select and from, and the last ON clause is on someTable.account_id instead of table2.account_id. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your answer, I'll validate it when I figure out if this is really how this works. 

Any idea why this works with PDO but not with MySql cli though ? That's the thing that's bugging me the most.

Comment: The query now works in phmyadmin when I use this syntax without modifying the data. I'm waiting to see if someone knows why this worked only on PDO before accepting your answer in order to have a complete answer.

Comment: I don't understand the 'table2 bbm', bbm is a table alias right ? Then why it's not used after that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two syntax variations in Standard SQL for writing multiple joins, the common one:

```
a join b on ... join c on ... join d on ...
```

and the strange one:

```
a join b join c join d on ... on ... on ...
```

In both cases the first ON is processed first, which means the strange syntax joins the first table in the last ON and the last table in the first ON, which is really hard to follow. That's why almost nobody is using it (but some tools might create it)

To change your strange

```
SELECT table1.something, table2.something 
FROM someTable
LEFT JOIN table1
  INNER JOIN table2 bbm
  ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
ON table1.account_id = someTable.account_id
```

to the common one move the last ON after the first join:

```
SELECT table1.something, table2.something 
FROM someTable
LEFT JOIN table1
  ON table1.account_id = someTable.account_id
INNER JOIN table2 bbm
  ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
```